# Get Highest Near Value in Google Sheets with formulas

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

Any optimal way to find near highest value in Google sheet using **inbuilt functions.**

I had already completed this using **Google Apps script** but I need a more reliable solution using Google Sheet Functions.

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C58-78X5o5HHTrN-JiNhpZbXa0gfOd3Ov4Qw0KbmVgo/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,{{0; SORT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(E3:AF22),,999^99)),,999^99)), " "))))},
 {MIN(E3:AF22); QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(E3:AF22),,999^99)),,999^99)), " ")))), "offset 1", 0); ""}}, 2, 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks! But I have just updated the dataset, It's does not working for it

Comment: Where,I updated the range as well,Can you please check a new sheet the problem still exist in that spreadsheet.

Comment: @Zamir check it out now

Comment: May,I know the problem, Whenever I increase the data,It stop's working for few cases.*I have updated the range as well.

Comment: I added the same formula in another sheet it is not working.